IISExpress stopped working after installing IBM MQ client 9.1.4 over 7.5
IBM MQ client 7.5 was already installed on the system which is primary. Then I installed IBM MQ client 9.1.4 and made it secondary.
After that my ASP.Net applications that I run from Visual Studio using IISExpress has stopped working which connects to 7.5. Web applications hosted on IIS are working fine. Any console or desktop application is also working fine.
Getting following error in Event Viewer when trying to connect to IBM MQ.
Faulting application name: iisexpress.exe, version: 10.0.26013.1000, time stamp: 0x64d3330b
Faulting module name: mqe.dll, version: 7.500.600.16058, time stamp: 0x56d1088a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x001b8a53
Faulting process id: 0x2c50
Faulting application start time: 0x01db027e8d333106
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\bin\mqe.dll
Report Id: f0a79957-2d1a-43f1-9eef-1d24090c2983
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Whether I run IISExpress as 32 bit or 64 bit doesn't matter. The user who is running Visual Studio is administrator and has full rights on machine. Any idea how to make it work?
EDIT
InstName:      Installation1
InstDesc:
Identifier:    1
InstPath:      C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ
Version:       7.5.0.6
Primary:       Yes
State:         Available
MSIProdCode:   {FC22F522-C043-4B56-BCC9-E8A7E1C3E530}
MSIMedia:      7.5 Client
MSIInstanceId: 1

InstName:      MQ9client
InstDesc:      mq9.1
Identifier:    2
InstPath:      C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ9Client
Version:       9.1.4.0
Primary:       No
State:         Available
MSIProdCode:   {2BD83773-D0AB-42EC-9CF6-7784E37653AD}
MSIMedia:      9.1 Server


Can you update your question with the output of dspmqinst? And does your app load MQ dlls from the GAC?

While 0xc0000005 means access violation, it doesn't mean the account you use (aka an administrator) has no permission, but rather the memory access was wrong due to some native code issues. And in your case, the old version of the library might never test against IIS Express. Can you completely uninstall 7.5 and only use 9.1?

@AttilaRepasi Output has been updated above.

@LexLi IISExpress was working fine with 7.5 before. In fact if I just uninstall 9.1 then it starts working again.

Went do you want to keep 7.5 which is over six years out of support from IBM?

It is recommended to verify if the installation of version 9.1 was performed in accordance with the guidelines provided by IBM, ensuring that no unintentional complications have arisen in version 7.5. Contacting IBM support for confirmation is advised.
